# JQuery String Concatenation within a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, concatenation, substitution

I'd like to preface this by saying I'm new to JQuery and this may be a simple question, but I was unable to find a solution after searching to the best of my ability.

I am trying to build a path to an image, where I am working with an API which returns an object that gives part of the path but not the base path.

Ex: 
Base path = Youtube.com/watch/?

Path piece from API: /gdsrhab

On line 29 you can see I am trying to perform string concatenation within trying to build the "results" string. I understand why this is not working the way I've set it up, but am not sure how to syntactically perform this (if possible).

I've also tried to create two variables: baseURL and apiURL, concatenate them and save the result into completeURL then substitute it in, but it JQuery takes the string literal "completeURL" instead of substituting the value of the variable. Could someone point me in the right direction for how to get the full path within the  tag? Thanks in advance for your help.

[Picture of my JQuery code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fGwc.png)

In the following picture you can see the second half of the path is missing
[The error message I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPAos.png)

Comment: insert your code here please

Comment: 404 means not found, so your path is wrong

Comment: Code is attached via the hyperlinks (I was unable to post picture due to my low post count). The issue was solved via the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [ES6 string templates](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) at start, so you only need to set your variable inside the ${}, you dont need to concate it, the string template will do it for you. So instead of

```
<img src = 'http...../' + '${movie.poster_path}'}>
```

that will output something like:

```
<img src="'http://yoururl.com/'+'mypath'"
```

you only need to do

```
<img src = 'http://yoururl.com/${movie.poster_path}'>
```

inside your string template

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. I'm sorry that this was such a nooby question and perhaps I did a poor job of explaining it given that people are down voting me, but your help means a lot. This did in fact resolve the issue for anyone reading this at a later time